# Re-label many factor rows with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to replicate the following behaviour with `dplyr` if that is possible.

It is pretty trivial what I am doing: I have a number of factors that have a certain baseline level, and I would like to simplify them to 0/1 variables.

If I simulate a data set like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:100,
                 x = factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 100, T)),
                 y = factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 100, T)))
```

Then I can easily achieve that like this:

```
fn <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x == "c", 0, 1)
}

df[c("x", "y")] <- apply(df[c("x", "y")], 2, fn) 
df
```

However in `dplyr` this seems to defeat me. I am thinking about using `mutate_which`, but i can't seem to get that to work with a custom function like `fn`.

Comment: What's the problem with `df %>% mutate(x = fn(x), y = fn(y))`?

Comment: Or `df %>% mutate_at(vars(x, y), funs(if_else(. == "c", 0, 1)))`

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by Psidon,

```
df %>% mutate(x = fn(x), y = fn(y))
```

is correct but not easily generalizable.

The answer proposed by Steven Beaupré is more generalizable:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(x:y), funs(if_else(. == "c", 0, 1)))
```

Or a more transparent version,

```
df %>% mutate_at(.funs = function(x) {ifelse(x == "c", 0, 1)}, .cols = vars(x:y))
```

My main problem was that this was not working with `mutate_each`, which seems to be phased out:

```
df %>% mutate_each(funs = function(x) {ifelse(x == "c", 0, 1)}, cols = vars(x, y))
Error: is.fun_list(calls) is not TRUE
```

Comment: The syntax in `mutate_each` is a little different, at least in previous versions. It's not `funs = ...` but `funs(...)`. So you can try `mutate_each(df, funs(as.integer(. != "c")), x:y)` instead